# I want to change my code for other result

Tags: python

I need to change something in my code for return the fibonacci sequence but the sequence must stop when the number will be more than the number of a sequence but in my case it give me a sequence with the same number of numbers

my try:

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    
    for k in range(n):
        c = b+a
        a = b
        b = c
        
    return a

for x in range(10):
  print(fib(x))
```

so this give me de sequence of 10

```
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
```

and this time I need that this sequence stop in 8 because 10 is bigger than 13

Comment: But I need to change the loop when b > than the number I put

Answer (score 0):

You can `break` when the limit is hit:

```
limit = 10
x = 0
while True:
    f = fib(x)
    if f > limit: break
    print(f)
    x += 1
```

Or (using `itertools.count` for an infinite loop):

```
from itertools import count

limit = 10
for x in count():
    f = fib(x)
    if f > limit: break
    print(f)
```

Another option is to make a generator:

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while a <= n:
        yield a
        c = b + a
        a = b
        b = c

for x in fib(10):
    print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

By taking your code and adding the condition, is that what you want?

```py
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    
    for k in range(n):
        c = b+a
        a = b
        b = c
        
    return a
    
i = 10
for x in range(i):
  if(fib(x) < i):
    print(fib(x))
```